# Непонятная ошибка в chrome

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку из-за которой [страничка](http://prozaik.16mb.com/works/pr_proto/slider_handmade/) не работает в `chrome`. Сообщение об ошибке такое:

[image: такое]

В `firefox` работает без проблем

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            // --------------------------------------------------------------------- PLUGIN kalininSlider INITIALIZATION------------
            $('#slider_wrap').kalininSlider({
                position: 1,
                slide_width: '300', //px
                effect: 'fade', //'slide', 'fade', 'angle'
                effectSpeed: 1000,
                animationSpeed: 1000,
                timer: 2000,
                arrows: true,
                indikator: 'buttons'    //'buttons', 'numeric'
                //autoSlide: true
            });
        });




// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ PLUGIN kalininSlider IMPLEMENTATION------------
(function($){
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- options ----------    
    $.fn.kalininSlider = function(options) {                    
        var options = jQuery.extend({
            position: 0,
            slide_width: '300', //px
            effect: 'slide',    //'slide', 'fade', 'angle'
            effectSpeed: 1000,
            animationSpeed: 1000,
            timer: 2000,
            arrows: true,
            indikator: 'buttons'    //'buttons', 'numeric'
            // autoSlide: true      
        },options); 



    return this.each(function() {
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ properties ---------  
        var self = $(this); 

        var slider_wrap_outer = $('#slider_wrap_outer'),
            slider_wrap = $('#slider_wrap'),
            slides_wrap = $('#slides_wrap'),
            slide_elem = slides_wrap.find('li'),
            slides_quantity = slide_elem.length,
            autoSlide = 0;  

        init(); 

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ methods ------------      
        function init(){
            slides_wrap.css('width', (slides_quantity * options.slide_width) + 'px');
            slider_wrap.css({
                width: options.slide_width + 'px',
                margin: '0 auto'
            });

            slider_wrap_outer.append('<div class="prev" id="prev" />').append('<div class="next" id="next" />');    

            if((options.indikator == 'numeric') || (options.indikator == 'buttons')){
                indikatorRender();
            }   

            controlsState(options.position);

            slidesState(options.position);      

            setIntervalAutoSlide();
        }

        function controlsState(position){
            var prev = $('#prev'),
                next = $('#next');

            (position == 0) ? prev.hide() : prev.show();
            (position == (slides_quantity - 1)) ? next.hide() : next.show();
        }

        function slidesState(position, oldPosition = options.position, key){
            var position_max = (slides_quantity - 1),
                prev_slide,
                oldPosition = oldPosition || options.position,
                key;                

            key = !key ? false : key;   

            console.log(position);  

            if(position < 0){
                options.position = 0;
            }
            else if(position > position_max){
                key == true ? options.position = 0 : options.position = position_max;
            }

            console.log(position + '__');   

            $('.indikator_element').removeClass('active').eq(position).addClass('active');

            switch (options.effect) {
                case 'slide':
                    shift(options.effectSpeed);

                    break;

                case 'fade':
                    dublicate(oldPosition)              

                    shift(0, function hideEffect(){
                        $('.cap').fadeOut(1000);    
                    });             

                    break;

                case 'angle':
                    dublicate(oldPosition)

                    shift(0, function hideEffect(){
                        $('.cap').hide(1000);   
                    });             

                    break;                      

                default:
                    alert('Эффект смены слайдов не выбран');

                    break;
            }   

            function dublicate(oldPosition){
                prev_slide = slide_elem.eq(oldPosition).clone().addClass('cap').appendTo('#slider').css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'top': 0,
                    'left': '60px',
                    'z-index': 100
                }); 
            }               

            function shift(effectSpeed, hideEffect){
                var hideEffect,
                    effectSpeed;

                !effectSpeed ? 0 : effectSpeed;

                !hideEffect ? false : hideEffect;

                slides_wrap.stop(true, true).animate({
                    marginLeft: -position * options.slide_width
                }, 100, hideEffect);            
            }       
        }

        function removeTrash(){
            $('.cap:hidden').remove();
        }

        function indikatorRender(){
            var i,
                num;

            slider_wrap.append('<ul id="indikator" class="indikator" />');

            for(i = 1; i <= slides_quantity; i++){
                (options.indikator == 'numeric') ? num = i : num = '';

                $('#indikator').append('<li class="indikator_element" id="indikatorElement_' + i + '" data-number="' + i + '">' + num + '</li>');
            }
        }

        function setIntervalAutoSlide(){
            if(options.autoSlide){
                autoSlide = window.setInterval( function(){
                                                    var oldPosition = options.position;

                                                    options.position++

                                                    if(options.position > slides_quantity){
                                                        options.position = 0;
                                                    }

                                                    slidesState(options.position, oldPosition, true); 

                                                    controlsState(options.position);

                                                    removeTrash();                                                          
                                                }, options.timer);
            }               
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ handlers -----------      
        function onClickControls(){
            var oldPosition = options.position;

            ($(this).attr('id') == 'prev') ? options.position-- : options.position++;

            slidesState(options.position, oldPosition);

            controlsState(options.position);

            removeTrash();
        }

        function onClickIndikator(){
            var oldPosition = options.position,
                indikNum = $(this).attr('data-number') - 1;

            options.position = indikNum;

            slidesState(indikNum, oldPosition);

            controlsState(options.position);

            removeTrash();
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ events -------------  
        $('#prev, #next').on('click', onClickControls); 

        $('.indikator_element').on('click', onClickIndikator);          
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: подключи более раннюю версию jquery, например 1.7 или 1.8.
В опере тоже такую ошибку выдает. Видимо ты неправильно слайдер написал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибку выше смотрели?

У вас функция содержит недопустимую конструкцию:

```
function slidesState(position, oldPosition = options.position, key = false)
```

В JavaScript нельзя задавать значения по умолчанию при объявлении функции.

Взамен можно сделать проверку аргументов в самом теле функции:

```
function slidesState(position, oldPosition, key) {
    /**
     * if(!oldPosition) {
     *    oldPosition =  options.position;
     * }
     */
    oldPosition = !oldPosition?options.position:oldPosition;

    /**
     * if(!key) {
     *    key = false;
     * }
     */    
    key = !key?false:key;

    //....
```

Comment: Как раз можно только в Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: А еще можно сократить код и писать: var oldPosition = oldPosition || options.position;

Comment: за замечание про аргументы спасибо. это я исправил, но ошибка осталась
http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/slider_handmade/

подключение более ранней версии jquery тоже не помогло

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin: Ошибку Вы не исправили до конца. `function slidesState(position, oldPosition = options.position, key){`. Уберите еще `oldPosition = options.position`.

Comment: моя невнимательность. спасибо, теперь всё работает